# Tengo problemas con la codificación a UTF-8 de una json obtenido de una URL

Tags: android, json, webservice, url, utf-8

Estoy consumiendo datos json desde una URL pero cuando muestro los datos en un listview no están en la codificación UTF-8 correctamente pues las tildes de los nombres no salen. Así es como me conecto a la url:

```
    String URL = "http://192.168.101.1/ilex/json.html";
    try {
        String result = "";
        //Accedemos al servicio web y leemos los datos devueltos en foramto  json
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sBuilder.toString();
        nat = new JSONObject(result);
```

este es el json, o sea lo que muestra la url si se acedira a ella desde un navegador normal:

```
{
"array":
[

{
"Nombre_Completo":"Alejandro Castillo Lopez",
"Telefono":"53908567"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Adrian Torres Gonzaléz",
"Telefono":"53421129"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Felix A. Marrero Pentón",
"Telefono":"54282442"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Mardiel Lisbani Nuñes Ortiz",
"Telefono":"53126509"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Reydier Bandomo Perez",
"Telefono":"54347845"
}
]
}
```

Al final creo un objeto JSON y por ahí lleno el listview. ¿Alguien sabe algo?

Comment: Verificaste si en tu base de datos no tienes problemas ?

Comment: no es una base de datos como tal, es un archivo.txt con el json dentro montada en  el WampServer y lo que ago es consumir de esa URL. No se si habra q ponerle alguna codificacion al txt o algo de eso...

Comment: muestra el contenido de ../json.html

Comment: Si deberias añadir tu JSON.HTML

Comment: ya edite la pregunta y puse mi json, no se por que no me sale como si fuera codigo. Es simplemente ese json pegado en un txt guardado como html y montado en el wampserver, @FelixBeeb

Comment: intenta colocar esto Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 en la cabezera de tu json

Comment: ¿Tienes el código que genera ese JSON? Todo apunta a que el error está en origen ya que el [RFC4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) indica que los datos deben estar OBLIGATORIAMENTE codificados en `Unicode`, `UTF-8` por defecto (punto 3: JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8). Así que lo que tendremos que ayudarte es con la correcta generación de ese JSON.

Comment: Debes mostrar el archivo `json.html`, no lo que el navegador te mostraría

Comment: el archivo json.html es el que publique arriba, justo eso, sin nada mas @GermanAlzate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Señores, ya di en el clavo...resulta que yo edito mi archivo .html(donde se encuentra el json) con el Notepad++, pues fui a Codificacion-Codificar en UTF-8 y listo, el texto se muestra correcatemente codificado en la aplicacion....

Answer (score 2):

He visto que esto ha sucedido y estas obteniendo correctamente la respuesta con el encoding correcto:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
```

Pero el problema seguramente es el archivo .html, este debe contener en el header el tipo de datos con codificación correcta:

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

agrega tu archivo .htm o el código que genera el .json dentro del .htm y podemos ayudarte a corregirlo.

---

Como consultas un archivo .html te sugiero agregués código html para caracteres acentuados, por ejemplo:

```
<html>
<body>
{
"array":
[

{
"Nombre_Completo":"Alejandro Castillo Lopez",
"Telefono":"53908567"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Adrian Torres Gonzal&eacute;z",
"Telefono":"53421129"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Felix A. Marrero Pent&oacute;n",
"Telefono":"54282442"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Mardiel Lisbani Nu&ntilde;es Ortiz",
"Telefono":"53126509"
},
{
"Nombre_Completo":"Reydier Bandomo Perez",
"Telefono":"54347845"
}
]
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya añadi mi archivo html, lo unico que tiene dentro es el json que muestro en la pregunta, mas nada, simplemente eso,  ningun codigo lo genera, yo solo  copio el json  para un txt, de doy guardar como html y punto...

Comment: hey nadie sabe nada por fin, he probado con   URLEncoder.encode(result, "UTF-8"); pero no funciona, y cuando aplico codigos html al rachivo .html en el <head> con la codificacion para q tenga utf-8 lo que hace es que en el navegador entonces no se ven las tildes y la app no consume el servicio...

Comment: El .json que agregaste es el que se muestra al cargar el .html?  podrías obtener el código fuente del html por favor, mediante botón derecho y la opción "Ver código fuente de la página"- @FelixAMarreroPentón

Comment: si ese es el json que se muestra al cargar el .html. El codigo fuentes es:      <html><head></head><body> .....json.....</body></html>    @Jorgesys

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón Felix agrega el código que agregué y trata de leerlo, comenta resultados.. Sinceramente no es común que una persona acceda a un html que en realidad tiene contenido html, lo ideal es acceder un .json.

Comment: si le pongo codigo html al archivo, o se a el head y el body no funciona el servicio cuando lo cargo con la aplicacion, no entiendo por que @Jorgesys

Comment: Felix, primeramente no veo la razón de usar un archivo html cuando el contenido es un .json, cambia la extension a .json (no agregues codigo html) y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Jorge El archivo en la extencion .json da el mismo resultado que en la extencion .html